# Android Thread is Getting Faster

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, android-viewpager, task

Here is my backgroundtask

```
   private Runnable backgroundTask= new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            for(int n=0; n<9000; n++) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                myHandler.post(foregroundTask);
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

And here is my froregroundtask

```
private Runnable foregroundTask= new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{

            konumlar[0]+=1;
            if (konumlar[0]==100)
                konumlar[0]=0;
            if (zaman<100)
            zaman++;
            for (int a=1;a<buses;a++){
                if(zaman>baslangic[a])
                    konumlar[a]+=1;
                if(konumlar[a]==100)
                    konumlar[a]=0;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

This is work good in first time . But after my thread is getting faster. It should be work every 1 second. But it is getting faster. I did not understand that. Also i am using that values some other classes.

```
@Override 
protected void onStart() { 
      super.onStart(); 
      Thread myThread1 = new Thread(backgroundTask, "backAlias1");     
      myThread1.start(); 
}
```

Comment: how are you running backgroundTask ?

Comment: Here '@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Thread myThread1 = new Thread(backgroundTask, "backAlias1");
       myThread1.start();
    }'

Comment: Also i am using 'konumlar[]' values intensely in other classes.Does it cause problem?

Comment: is `konumlar` shared between threads ?

Comment: No. How can i share it ?

Comment: @lovekrand I recommend *against* using `Thread` and use a `Timer` http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html an example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730902/android-simple-time-counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you start couple Threads when coming back to #start Method, as you not stopping the old one.

Comment: Yes you should be right . OnStart method is working again .Thanks