# Display Image for Numbers in Count

Tags: android

I have created a `roundbutton`. I want to display this `roundbutton` for the number in the `count`. The count represents the number of `button presses`. For example if the `count` equals 2 then 2 `roundbutton` must appear on the screen. Instead of me having to put each button on the screen and making it `invisible` at first then `visible` depending on the `count`.

#### roundbutton

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#FF2A2A" />
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make timer and change your image each second, but because that will be a timer...you need to change your image in runnable method, which will be behaving like UI thread.

Comment: @Jevgenjj Kononov is there a link as to show me how to achieve your above answer?

Comment: Try to look at this link: https://dzone.com/articles/how-schedule-task-run-interval

1. try create timer and ouput to logs time
2. inside that timer (where you updating  your time) update your gui
 but update should be done with runnable method (Ui main thread)

Comment: This link will be better: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730902/android-simple-time-counter

Comment: Timer T=new Timer();
    T.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {         
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myTextView.setText("count="+count);
                count++;                
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jevgenij Kononov

Answer (score 0):

In your code, after count change you might change back by:

```
btnBack.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_camera);
```

also for change visibility you can use:

```
View.setVisibility(View.GONE / View.VISIBLE / View.INVISIBLE)
```